# what is the format to import a excel file for creating new generic product in aspdotnetstorefront?

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I am trying to import a excel file for creating new product which have the fields like (product Name,Product Type,Manufacturer,Variant Name, Price) but I found it is not in a correct format.Can anyone provide me sample excel file format to create new generic product in aspdotnetstorefront.

Answer (score 0):

Within the downloaded software look for this file

AspDotNetStoreFront>Web>ImportFileSamples>ExcelImport.xls

This is the template that you should use. Don't delete any of the top three rows. What version of ASPDNSF are you using? The format changed from 9.0 onwards to include SEALtext columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am using AspDotNetStoreFront 9.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links with how to do the import, what the fields are and various sample spreadsheets.

http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-707-import-from-excel-file.aspx
http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-958-excel-product-import.aspx
http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-906-excel-product-import-fields.aspx